# How do I use T-SQL Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I know I need to have (although I don't know why) a `GROUP BY` clause on the end of a SQL query that uses any aggregate functions like `count`, `sum`, `avg`, etc:

```
SELECT count(userID), userName
FROM users
GROUP BY userName
```

When else would `GROUP BY` be useful, and what are the performance ramifications?

Comment: Note that 'GROUP BY' does not order the result set. If you require a particular order, then add ORDER BY too

Comment: A better way of putting that is that the SQL standard does not guarantee any ordering when using it... But how do you implement grouping without ordering? All implementations I've seen use ordering of some kind, and almost always return results in order as a side effect.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To retrieve the number of widgets from each widget category that has more than 5 widgets, you could do this:

```
SELECT WidgetCategory, count(*)
FROM Widgets
GROUP BY WidgetCategory
HAVING count(*) > 5
```

The "having" clause is something people often forget about, instead opting to retrieve all their data to the client and iterating through it there.

Answer (score 15):

GROUP BY is similar to DISTINCT in that it groups multiple records into one.

This example, borrowed from http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7080.asp, lists distinct products in the Products table.

```
SELECT Product FROM Products GROUP BY Product

Product
-------------
Desktop
Laptop
Mouse
Network Card
Hard Drive
Software
Book
Accessory
```

The advantage of GROUP BY over DISTINCT, is that it can give you granular control when used with a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT Product, count(Product) as ProdCnt
FROM Products
GROUP BY Product
HAVING count(Product) > 2

Product      ProdCnt
--------------------
Desktop          10
Laptop            5
Mouse             3
Network Card      9
Software          6
```

Answer (score 3):

Group By forces the entire set to be populated before records are returned (since it is an implicit sort).

For that reason (and many others), never use a Group By in a subquery.

Comment: Golly, I think you were the only one who answered the _"performance"_ aspect of the question. +1

Answer (score 2):

Counting the number of times tags are used might be a google example:

```
SELECT TagName, Count(*)
AS TimesUsed
FROM Tags
GROUP BY TagName ORDER TimesUsed
```

If you simply want a distinct value of tags, I would prefer to use the `DISTINCT` statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TagName
FROM Tags
ORDER BY TagName ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY also helps when you want to generate a report that will average or sum a bunch of data. You can GROUP By the Department ID and the SUM all the sales revenue or AVG the count of sales for each month.