# Plant Shift Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I'm generating a Plant-shift report:

In my application, I'm providing a dropdownlist for selecting shift and plant and they will select a date from calender

**I have 3 shifts**

- shift1 starts at 7am and ends at 3pm
- shift2 starts at 3pm and ends at 11pm
- shift3 starts at 11pm and ends at 3am

**I have a table called datalogging where login information will be stored as shown below:**

```
Name       Shiftname    operatorname      Date           plantname      line       Machine 
Pradeepa   Shift2(11-7)  Operator 3     2011-05-28       Plant 3        Line5     mc10 
Ashwini   Shift1(7-3)    Operator 1     2011-05-29       Plant 3        Line6     mc12 
Deepika   Shift2(11-7)   Operator 3     2011-05-29       Plant 5        Line9     mc18 
Ashwini   Shift1(7-3)    Operator 1     2011-05-24       Plant 1        Line1     mc1 
Deepika   Shift2(3-11)   Operator 2     2011-05-24       Plant 2        Line3     mc5 
Ashwini   Shift2(3-11)   Operator 2     2011-05-25       Plant 2        Line3     mc5
```

and so on..

I have a parameter table like temperature,pressure,ph,speed,co2 etc

Temperature table contains following data and this table will contains all the reading from 7am to till 3am

**This is Temperature table reading**

```
Temperature      Time              Date 
27  1900-01-01 13:46:37.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.3    1900-01-01 13:51:37.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.6    1900-01-01 13:56:37.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.9    1900-01-01 14:01:37.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.2    1900-01-01 14:06:37.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.5    1900-01-01 14:11:37.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.8    1900-01-01 14:16:37.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27  1900-01-01 15:09:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.3    1900-01-01 15:11:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.6    1900-01-01 15:13:53.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.9    1900-01-01 15:15:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.2    1900-01-01 15:17:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.5    1900-01-01 15:19:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.8    1900-01-01 15:21:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
29.1    1900-01-01 15:23:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
29.4    1900-01-01 15:25:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
29.7    1900-01-01 15:27:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
30  1900-01-01 15:29:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
30.3    1900-01-01 07:03:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
30.6    1900-01-01 07:05:11.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
30.9    1900-01-01 07:07:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
31.2    1900-01-01 07:09:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
31.5    1900-01-01 07:11:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
31.8    1900-01-01 07:13:11.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
31.8    1900-01-01 07:15:11.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
32.1    1900-01-01 07:17:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
32.4    1900-01-01 07:19:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
32.7    1900-01-01 07:21:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
33  1900-01-01 07:23:11.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27  1900-01-01 09:03:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.3    1900-01-01 09:05:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.6    1900-01-01 09:07:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.9    1900-01-01 09:09:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.2    1900-01-01 09:11:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.5    1900-01-01 09:13:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.8    1900-01-01 09:15:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
29.1    1900-01-01 09:17:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
29.4    1900-01-01 09:19:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
29.4    1900-01-01 09:21:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
29.7    1900-01-01 09:23:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
30  1900-01-01 09:25:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
30.3    1900-01-01 09:27:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27  1900-01-01 10:33:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.3    1900-01-01 10:35:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.6    1900-01-01 10:37:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
27.9    1900-01-01 10:39:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
28.2    1900-01-01 10:41:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
```

**this is my pressure reading**

```
Pressure      Time                       Date
0.5 1900-01-01 13:46:36.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
0.9 1900-01-01 13:51:36.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
1.3 1900-01-01 13:56:36.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
1.7 1900-01-01 14:01:36.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.1 1900-01-01 14:06:36.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.5 1900-01-01 14:11:36.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.9 1900-01-01 14:16:36.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
0.5 1900-01-01 15:09:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
0.9 1900-01-01 15:11:51.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
1.3 1900-01-01 15:13:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
1.7 1900-01-01 15:15:52.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.1 1900-01-01 15:17:51.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.5 1900-01-01 15:19:51.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.9 1900-01-01 15:21:51.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
3.3 1900-01-01 15:23:51.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
3.7 1900-01-01 15:25:51.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.1 1900-01-01 15:27:51.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.5 1900-01-01 15:29:51.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.9 1900-01-01 07:03:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
5.3 1900-01-01 07:05:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
5.7 1900-01-01 07:07:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
6.1 1900-01-01 07:09:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
6.5 1900-01-01 07:11:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
6.9 1900-01-01 07:13:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
6.9 1900-01-01 07:15:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
7.3 1900-01-01 07:17:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
7.7 1900-01-01 07:19:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
8.1 1900-01-01 07:21:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
8.5 1900-01-01 07:23:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
0.5 1900-01-01 09:03:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
0.9 1900-01-01 09:05:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
1.3 1900-01-01 09:07:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
1.7 1900-01-01 09:09:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.1 1900-01-01 09:11:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.5 1900-01-01 09:13:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.9 1900-01-01 09:15:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
3.3 1900-01-01 09:17:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
3.3 1900-01-01 09:19:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
3.7 1900-01-01 09:21:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.1 1900-01-01 09:23:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.5 1900-01-01 09:25:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.9 1900-01-01 09:27:09.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
0.5 1900-01-01 10:33:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
0.9 1900-01-01 10:35:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
1.3 1900-01-01 10:37:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
1.7 1900-01-01 10:39:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.1 1900-01-01 10:41:10.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.5 1900-01-01 17:02:57.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
2.9 1900-01-01 17:04:57.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
3.3 1900-01-01 17:06:57.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
3.7 1900-01-01 17:08:57.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.1 1900-01-01 17:10:57.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.5 1900-01-01 17:12:57.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
4.9 1900-01-01 17:14:57.000 2011-06-07 00:00:00
```

and so on..

The user will select a line from dropdownlist and shift and he will select a date from th calender If the user select shift1,plant 1 and date 07/06/2011 what are the readings are there between 7am to 3pm should be displayed in my report

**My report should look like:**

```
Machine     Shiftname   Date               Time             Temperature     Pressure
mc1         Shift1      2011/06/07      07:03:10.000          30.3           4.9
mc1         Shift1      2011/06/07      07:05:11.000          30.6           5.3
mc1         Shift1      2011/06/07      07:07:10.000          30.9           5.7
```

like this I want all the reading from temprature, pressure, ph, co2, d02 the table from 7 to 3pm

can any one help me on this.

Comment: it throwing error as The multi-part identifier "P.Time" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  DL.Machine, 
  DL.ShiftName,
  @MyDate,
  case when T.Time is null then P.Time else T.Time end as Time,
  T.Temperature,
  NULL as Pressure
From
  DataLogging as DL
  inner join Temperature as T on "reading time is within this shift's timespan"
Where
  DL.Date = @MyDate
  and DL.ShiftName = @MyShiftName

UNION

Select 
  DL.Machine, 
  DL.ShiftName,
  @MyDate,
  case when T.Time is null then P.Time else T.Time end as Time,
  NULL as Temperature,
  P.Pressure
From
  DataLogging as DL
  inner join Pressure as P on "reading time is within this shift's timespan"
Where
  DL.Date = @MyDate
  and DL.ShiftName = @MyShiftName
```

**Let me explain the method here...**

1. Start off with DataLogging. You are concerned with the employee who had a particular shift. You define that employee in the `WHERE` clause by specifying an input DATE and input SHIFT.
2. Join up with the `Temperature` table, because you want to see all the temperature readings from that person's shift.
3. Join up with the `Pressure` table, because you want to see all the pressure readings from that person's shift.
4. Why do we `UNION`? Well, mainly to prevent dupes (Dupes would exist if we joined with both readings-tables in the same Select statement). As you've noticed, it's hard to join Temperature readings and Pressure readings because they have different timestamps. If they are one second apart, then there is nothing to join on. Therefore, I think the best solution is to simply have a record per reading as I have done above. The above will list all Temperature readings first, followed by all Pressure Readings -- and combine them into the same Table that is returned via the `UNION`.

**Note:** You should probably be using a `datetime` field instead of a `Date` column and a Time column, because it will store both the date and the time in one field.

**Note:** You can combine those readings that have the same date & time by using a subquery and [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702/how-do-i-use-t-sql-group-by) the [subquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx) on the Time.

**Note:** `"reading time is within this shift's timespan"` is included above to indicate some code you need to fill in. You will probably want to use a [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement to adjust the `ON Clause` to only include those items with a particular shift

**References**

- [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

Comment: no im storing date and time seperately and im fetching data based on shift.