# SQL Query relationship coding

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need some help making this work please.  Some help please to ensure I always return just one row per **ProductID**. My Product Table contains base information on Products which can be properties in this case.  It links to the Properties table via a ProductCode.

What I would like is to have the query return just the one row which it really should. Essentially, the row should display the PropertyLabel whether or not there are values in the PropertyProductValues table for that particular propertyLabel. The code below returns a bunch of rows which really it shouldn't, or I don't want it to. And I would appreciate help fine tuning this please. thanks in Advance.

```
Create Table Product 
{
    ProductID uniqueidentifier, 
    ProductName Varchar(50),
    ProductCode Varchar(50)

}

Create Table Properties
{
     PropertyID uniqueidentifier, 
     PropertyProductcode Varchar(50)

}

Create Table PropertyProductValues
{
    ID uniqueidentifier,
    PropertyID  uniqueidentifier,
    ProductID    uniqueidentifier,
    PropertyLabel Varchar(50),
    UnitID uniqueidentifier

}

Create Table unit
{
    UnitID uniqueidentifier,
    Unit Varchar(50)
}

   Select productid , PropertyLabel
PropertyValue
PropertyUnit 
from Product 
inner join Properties on ProductCode =  PropertyProductCode
left join PropertyProductValues on Properties.PropertyID = ProductProductValues.PropertyID 
left join Unit on PropertyValues.UnitID = Unit.UnitID
    Where ltrim(rtrim(lower(PropertyLabel))) = lower('Special')
```

### Sample Data

```
Product Table 
b0359c76-8622-4006-82f2-1b4c91a8f6b3   Brown Building   YSHJT
aba475c4-5a5c-483a-9faa-67f67ff9672d   Sket Building       GTJHD54
8f645348-8871-4fad-8c85-9fc6a1169b33    HOUSE 9           DGFS345


Properties Table

27c6485b-f7a5-4243-9304-71939230964d     DGFS345
88e911e5-bf40-4f14-89cc-4ed2984c342e     GTJHD54
d217cc14-6fcb-4251-a6d7-8fd1b3398a32      YSHJT
689cfd9d-bc87-4e23-afb3-d6cbf1e961f6       FFFSRW
bf7ae151-2e3f-4e0a-bf8b-d44ef30cf276        WYSJD

PropertyProductValues Table

6cf47434-c834-455d-a606-3d10cb9f7ab3       b0359c76-8622-4006-82f2-1b4c91a8f6b3    b0359c76-8622-4006-82f2-1b4c91a8f6b3       Storey           
82ee0f80-afe4-45c2-877c-e79ce286170f         27c6485b-f7a5-4243-9304-71939230964d   b0359c76-8622-4006-82f2-1b4c91a8f6b3       Bedrooms     
5ff7f809-6b1f-4d6c-a125-29ce67f097d7         27c6485b-f7a5-4243-9304-71939230964d    8f645348-8871-4fad-8c85-9fc6a1169b33        Bathrooms
7f634b81-1212-4223-af42-29b4dc2bafcc         27c6485b-f7a5-4243-9304-71939230964d     aba475c4-5a5c-483a-9faa-67f67ff9672d        Material
cae10884-edf0-4340-bde6-5207e28a07cc         689cfd9d-bc87-4e23-afb3-d6cbf1e961f6         b0359c76-8622-4006-82f2-1b4c91a8f6b3      Basement
83943759-39d7-406e-92ea-4202a9b1d716        bf7ae151-2e3f-4e0a-bf8b-d44ef30cf276         b0359c76-8622-4006-82f2-1b4c91a8f6b3      Storey
c045d0ff-34db-4427-9fb7-fd41fc92f310          bf7ae151-2e3f-4e0a-bf8b-d44ef30cf276         aba475c4-5a5c-483a-9faa-67f67ff9672d         balcony

Unit Table 

UNITID                                       UNIT
3a4a5216-0704-495e-b0a7-560787e0847a         kg
6b4493f6-c2e4-4682-b71d-93cb1893eb73          m
2f2b4fee-9e69-4a71-a098-36e2da71471e          l
55c8e5bf-edde-4977-ab7b-8827e337a31e          oz
19528647-bd9f-48e0-ba86-b722d5b8ab0e          cm
cee5cd46-1ae4-4b49-8b1c-9b3e0bd5270f          mm
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2702/1355166) may help.

Comment: Any thougts on **how** are we supposed to choose one record?, what is the criteria?.....what do you mean with *returns a bunch of rows which really it shouldn't, or I don't want it to*, are they wrong?, duplicated?, what is it that you actually want?

Comment: There should really be only one row returned is what I mean.

Comment: Can you show some sample data for each table and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave the table structure of your 3 tables, but in principle, to get 1 row per PropertyId, you'll be doing a `GROUP BY PropertyId`.

Comment: A Group By does not seem to give me the effect I need. The Group by displays about 7 rows per productID