# SQL Sum total for same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

This is my data:

```
column1   columnAmount
-----------------------
  ab           3
  ac           2
  ab           4
```

So in my query I want to sum the values which are the same in the colum1.

My desired output would be:

```
column1    columnAmount
----------------------    
  ab           7
  ac           2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use T-SQL Group By](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702/how-do-i-use-t-sql-group-by)

Comment: Isn't this a bit too trivial? Read about SQL, group by, aggregate functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic `SUM ... GROUP BY`

```
SELECT column1,
       Sum(columnAmount) AS columnAmount
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY column1
```

As the syntax suggests it divides the input into groups (one for each distinct value of `column1`) and calculates the sum for each group.

Comment: If I had more columns I would have to add them on the group by clause, but the query will still group it by the first one specified on the group by clause right?

Comment: @pyram - No you would need to put those in an aggregate too. If you put them in the `GROUP BY` you would get a group for each distinct combination of values. If they are functionally dependant on `column1` then you could add them to the `GROUP BY` list as that wouldn't alter the grouping but it isn't clear that this is the case from your question.

Comment: I didn't understood completely your comment above. the thing is I have more than these 2 columns on the table, these other columns contain text. So when I run the query, it asks me to put these other columns on the group by clause..........so, should I just add them on the group by clause after column1?

Comment: @pyram - You're better off editing your question to something that represents your actual situation as I haven't really got time at the moment to discuss it. Particularly you need to show whether there might be more than one value in a `column1` group for any of these additional columns and if so how that should be handled in the desired results.

Comment: I think I have the answer as it is. Thanks for all the help!