# How to remove duplicate records from sql query result after joining multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, join

Any assistance with the following will be very much appreciated;

After joining multiple tables using the following script to gather the information I require I now have multiple duplicate records in the result.

I am unable to use distinct so how can I get rid of the duplicates results in the select statement before exporting it?

```
use Cohort

select *

from patients

join immunisations
on patients.patient_id = immunisations.patient_id

join titles
on patients.title_id = titles.title_id

join courses
on immunisations.course_id = courses.course_id

join departments
on patients.patient_id = departments.department_id

join employees
on patients.patient_id = employees.post_title_id
```

Best regards

Louise

Comment: Distinct will not work because you are using *. You need to specify the columns you want to keep and try distinct again.

Comment: You need to read up on SQL basics before posting questions on here. Learn about using the `GROUP BY` clause: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use T-SQL Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702/how-do-i-use-t-sql-group-by)

Comment: Why can't you use distinct? What's the sample data and expected output? Are the entire rows duplicates or are you focusing on a single column?

Comment: @RossBush Of course it will "work" - if by "work" you mean execute successfully.

    set nocount on;
    with cte as (select * from (values (1, 's'), (2, 'b'), (1, 's'), (3, 'z')) as b(id, val))
    select distinct * from cte
    order by id;

Given the joins and lack of column list, it is doubtful that distinct will be useful here.

Comment: Hello Ross Thank you for your feedback. I am aware that I cannot use select * distinct. The script I put on the post was merely the one I used to get the data I required.

Comment: Hello Tanner Your response was really helpful.

Comment: Hi SCSimon I cannot use distinct because there are no distinct rows in the result. For example some patients have had mulitple immunisations that are the same and any objects return a result of null. I cant find anythink unique to use in a distinct statement. I hope that makes sense? Just to be clear I am not looking to remove duplicates from the database just remove them from the query results. Best regards Louise

Comment: Hi Scmor  Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

@Rossbush @SMor

Hey guys, between the 2 of you, you have helped me to resolve the issue for which I am truly grateful.

This is what I did which worked;

```
use Cohort

select distinct
    patients.first_name,
    patients.last_name,
    patients.dob,
    titles.description,
    courses.description,
    departments.description,
    immunisations.date_due,
    immunisations.date_given,
    immunisations.comments
from patients
    join immunisations on patients.patient_id = immunisations.patient_id
    join titles on patients.title_id = titles.title_id
    join courses on immunisations.course_id = courses.course_id
    join departments on patients.patient_id = departments.department_id
    join employees on patients.patient_id = employees.post_title_id
```

Many thanks

Louise